# How to convert an array of 8 bytes into a 32-bit number, if the system does not support 64-bit arithmetic

Tags: arrays, numbers, byte

I have an array of 8 bytes representing some huge number, e.g.
11017125042 decimal - as bytes it looks like 00 00 00 02 90 AB FC B2.

I want to convert the 8 bytes into a 32-bit signed integer, getting rid of last 4 digits.

In case you wonder, that's a position value, where one revolution is 1 billion units, so the value means 11.017125042 revolutions. I don't need such absurd resolution, so I want to get the initial value divided by 10 000 - 1101712 instead of 11017125042.

The tricky part is that the system (a Siemens PLC) does not support 64-bit arithmetic.
Any idea how to do it?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered using REAL or LREAL to store this value? I don't know what your Siemens PLC model is, but it is quite possible that it has some form of floating point value that you can use.

Comment: 10 = 5\*2, so 10000 = 10^4 = 5^4 \* 2^4. You can do a truncating divide by 16 by just shifting right by 4 bits, then do a floating point divide of what's left by 625. Might be accurate enough for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments but I don't understand. 

Storing the value into LREAL is fine, but how do I put the value there? How to convert 8 bytes representing a signed 64-bit integer to LREAL, when I can't perform any operation with integers larger than 0xFFFFFFFF? LREAL is the only 64-bit datatype supported by the PLC (S7-1200), there are no 64-bit integers.

As for shifting right by 4, or even by 8 bits - the rest is still an integer larger than 32 bits so I can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in a SCL block or SCL network of a LAD/FBD block.

```
#posLrealDiv10k :=
+ #posBytes[7] * 0.0001 //remove if you don't care
+ #posBytes[6] * 0.0256 //remove if you don't care
+ #posBytes[5] * 6.5536 //...
+ #posBytes[4] * 1677.7216
+ #posBytes[3] * 429496.7296
+ #posBytes[2] * 109951162.7776
+ #posBytes[1] * 28147497671.0656
+ #posBytes[0] * 7205759403792.7936;
```

[image: S7-1200 code simulation]

The SIOS forum is usually quite helpful with this sort of conversion problem.  Just not this particular one, it seems.